# How to install the Mercurial plug-in in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I had downloaded Mercurial for eclipse, i also saw the video about how to set up the plug-in in eclipse. In this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OBg6Zv0Tns
They import it in eclipse using file > import. But when i do the same, there is no option like Mercurial shown. Also, after that they copy paste some link in the given box.(I don't know what it is exactly, as i haven't been able to reach till there.) Where do they copy this link from, they don't show it clearly. I tried searching for it on their website, but their website is hopeless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Import part comes after installing the plugin. To install plugin in eclipse go to, Help->Install new Software

In work with give this url: http://hge.javaforge.com/mercurialeclipse-snapshots

You will see name, Mercurial Eclipse snapshot releases. Check the box next to it and go next and finish it.

After restart you should see the Mercurial folder after doing a File->Import